# Is there a word to describe the desire to not have desires

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Basically the title. I want a word to describe wanting to not want. For example, if I wanted use this word in a sentence to say I don’t want to be materialistic:

I wish I could be more [insert word] with materialism because it’s too much work to keep getting stuff.

Comment: *apathetic, zen, ...*

Comment: I think your problem is trying to have "more" of a lack of something.  It's a fundamentally confusing logical proposition.  Why not just say "I wish I could be less materialistic"?

Comment: Detached, dispassionate?

Comment: How about "maniaphobia"?

Comment: How about “desireless”?

Comment: Wanting a different desire that is more, better or different than other desires is hardly an antidote to desire.  I don't want to edify more of the flawed framework which you (or at least your sentence) have already said are the problem. The end of desire is in finding "(self-)sufficiency," "living in abundance" (with less), being (already) "enough," and knowing one's "value" and "worth" as pre-existing and separate from anything that is acquired.  These are the words and concepts which are used by those who write about these issues.

Answer (score 1):

The word *apathetic*, already suggested in a comment, can be traced back to the Greek word for the Stoic ideal that incorporates what you have in mind. It can be used in the present-day English for those who pursue similar ideals, but only if the context prepares the readers/listeners to take it that way, for example, by explicitly referring to Stoicism. Without such a context, the word is likely to be understood by the present-day English speakers to stand for something highly undesirable, rather than an ideal to be pursued.

One device that is sometimes used to make it clear that one wishes to refer to the Stoic ideal, rather than to the apathy in the sense of the present-day psychology, is to use the transliteration of the original Greek term for the former: *apatheia*. One can thus say, for example, that one is pursuing apatheia in one’s life, and one will be understood, by the philosophically educated, to be pursuing some Stoicism-inspired ideal. The obvious disadvantage of this device is that only people with at least some philosophical education will ‘get’ it. It should also be noted that *apatheia* is a noun, and that it might be awkward to try to make out of it an adjective that would work well within English sentences.

Another theory that incorporates what you have in mind is Buddhism. The word *buddhist* can sometimes be heard in everyday English conversations in the loose sense that covers that outlook that you are seeking to name, without implying a serious commitment to Buddhism in all its details. If you use the word that way, you will probably be understood. You should, however, bear in mind that those who are seriously committed to Buddhism may disapprove of the word being used too loosely.

None of these terms, incidentally, works well with the phrase ‘with materialism’ in your sample sentence. You should probably say that you reject materialism (in the relevant sense) separately from saying what it is that you do accept and pursue.

Answer (score 0):

The control of one's actions suggested by willing oneself to not want is *restraint*. Accordingly, someone who consistently refused desire would be **restrained**. Oxford English Dictionary, "[restrained, adj.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/164005)":

> Kept under control; characterized by reserve or moderation.

Merriam-Webster, "[Restrained](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/restrained)":

> : marked by restraint : not excessive or extravagant

Restraint involves keeping a desire under control, which in turn implies the metacognition that you not want (on a higher level) what you want (on a baser level). For example, I *restrain* myself from reaching for another cookie. Around the cookie jar, I practice *restraint*. Sometimes, I wish I were more **restrained** around the cookie jar.

Similarly, for your example:

> I wish I could be more **restrained** with [respect to] materialism because it’s too much work to keep getting stuff.

Also, using a word that doesn't rely on a negative prefix helps avoid the stylistic awkwardness of saying you're "more un-*something*" rather than "less *something.*"

Answer (score 0):

Someone who is highly self-disciplined and avoids all forms of indulgence can be described as (an) ***ascetic***. An ascetic resists desire in all its forms - it effectively describes an existence that is free from acting on want.

Comment: I’m trying to focus less on the extrinsic aspect and more on the intrinsic. For example there is a difference between not wanting to kill and not killing. Ascetic is more about resisting temptations, whereas I’m trying to say I want to feel less tempted

Answer (score 0):

First word that came to me was ***disinterested***:

> *I wish I could be more **disinterested** with materialism ...*

It is more idiomatic to use *disinterested in*, but it seems to work well in your context.

> **2** Having or feeling no interest in something.
>   *‘her father was so **disinterested** in her progress that he only visited the school once’*
>   <sub>[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disinterested)</sub>

Comment: What about 'detached'?